# Joint PDF of dependent random variables

Tags: probability

How would you solve the below

> Let X and Y be random variables with joint probability density function (PDF) given by:
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}cxy &: x \ge 0, y \ge 0, x + y \le 2\\ 0&: \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) Find $c$.
>
> (b) Find $\Bbb E [XY ]$.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Seems like a homework question! tell us what you've figured out so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: Also, to get to know how I nicely typeset your question, and other information about writing maths at this site, see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: Please read the FAQ and learn the proper etiquette for posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture. Let $T$ be the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(0,2)$. We want to choose $c$ so that
$$\iint_T cxy \,dy\,dx=1.$$
To evaluate the integral, express it as the iterated integral
$$\int_{x=0}^2\left(\int_{y=0}^{2-x} cxy\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

For $E(XY)$, we want
$$\iint_T (xy)(cxy)\,dy\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank you... Now I can see where I went wrong... in solving I find that

Comment: @Eric: You are welcome. But your comment got cut off, probably inadvertently pressed the Enter key. It is a flaw in the system, used to get me a lot. So I do not know what number you got.

Comment: In solving for C I find that C=1 , However I am at a lost of how to solve for the numerical value of E(XY).  Since that are dependent variables would I need to solve for them separately?? Would I evaluate on the same integral as C was evaluated.

Comment: The answer says what to do. Integrate $xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over the plane, which comes down to integrating $(xy)(cxy)$ over the triangle. By the way, I do not get $1$ for $c$. The first integral is $cx(2-x)^2/2)=c(2x-2x^2 +x^3/2)$. Integrating with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $2$ gives $2c/3$, so $c=3/2$. Do check your work, and please note that I could have made an arithmetical error.

Comment: can you please inform where the 2c/3 derived from ... when I integrate for c I keep coming up with 2c/2 which would make c= 1

Comment: Integrate $c\left(2x-2x^2+\frac{x^3}{2}\right)$. We get $c\left(x^2-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{x^4}{8}\right)$. Plug in $2$, take away the result of plugging in $0$. We get $\frac{2c}{3}$.

Comment: Oh, I've got it... thanks so much ... It appears I need to brush up on a lot more math concepts then I thought.

Comment: You are welcome. I imagine it was a minor slip in the integration. Probability calculations can involve fairly involved integrations.

Comment: I've been struggling with the integration of (xy)(cxy) over the triangle. Can you please map it out for me as well. I will use it as a basis to working additonal double integral problems.Thanks

Comment: We first integrate $\frac{3}{2}x^2y^2$ with respect to $y$, from $0$ to $2-x$. We get $\frac{1}{2}x^2(2-x)^3$. Expand the cube, multiply by $x^2$. We get $\frac{1}{2}(8x^2 -12x^3+6x^4-x^5)$. Integrate term by term, plug in $2$, take away the result of plugging in $0$. We get an unpleasant quantity of slightly messy fractions. Simplify.